# How to get the leading whitespaces of a bash variable

Tags: bash, shell

for example, the variable is like:

```
ANY='    ab1 de$%   '
```

The middle part 'ab1 de$%' can be any combination of characters.

I want to get the substring of leading whitespaces, to indent other lines.

Comment: What do you want to trim off? Just the `graph` characters (e.g. `ab1de$%`)? or also the trailing whitespace?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use *search-and-replace* `parameter substitution`:

```
leading_whitespace="${ANY/[^[:space:]]*/}"
```

**EDIT:**

Or also *substring-removal* `parameter substitution` as mentioned by [David C. Rankin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3422102/david-c-rankin) below:

```
leading_whitespace="${ANY%%[![:space:]]*}"
```

Comment: `[^[:space:]]*` might be closer to the problem specification.

Comment: *parameter-expansion w/substring removal* also works `lws="${any%%[![:space:]]*}"`

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin – that is an elegant alternative as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `sed`:

```
leading=$(sed -E 's/^([[:space:]]+).*/\1/' <<< "$string")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use parameter expansion of `${parameter%%word}`.

```
leading=${ANY%%[[:graph:]]*}
```

Comment: I would favor the solution by **David C. Rankin** – `lws="${ANY%%[![:space:]]*}"` for the reason mentioned by **rici** [above](http://stackoverflow.com/a/44016003/4279440) – in that is more closely matches the problem description.